# max35101(ultrasonic watermeter)

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, embedded-resource, firmware

I tried to initialize max35101 ic. This ic used in ultrasonic water meter. I sent  the below commands but I didn't get any response.

Commands are,

```
0xFE0004(POWER ON SET)
0x310100()
0x380f10(bias charge,pulse lanch freq)
0x39A370(DUTY CYCLE)
0X3A0610,0X3BO90A,0X3C0B0C,0X3D0000,0X3E000
```

Comment: Totally unclear: did you test your HW before to ask? How are you sending those commands?

Comment: yes, I tested HW ,working is good,after that I send some commands. I am using spi protocol. main purpose of this project measurement time.

Answer (score 0):

How to interface max35101 ic with R5F10RLCAFB Contoroller.Main purpose is time measured.which commands I have to send to max35101.